# PHP to calculate a total_amount

Tags: php, for-loop

I am a little stuck with some calculations on my booking system.

The pricing structure for Deposits is as follows

**package1 = £20**

**package2 = £40**

So if a user bought package1 and package2 the maths would be £60..

But at the moment my code looks as follows :

```
// Do Some Maths To Show The New Total To Be Paid...
        foreach($this->session->userdata['booking_data']['bikes'] as $bikes)
        {
            $amount = 0;

            if($bikes == 'package1')
            {
                $amount += '20';
            }
            else
            {
                $amount += '40';
            }

            $total_amount = $amount;
        }
```

My string(s) look as follows, So the maths should be **£60** but its coming out at **£40**

I am currently using package1 and package2.

Thanks in advance on this one.

I may just be over complicating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `$amount = 0;` before the `foreach` and remove `$total_amount = $amount;` and it will work (`$amount` will contain what you need).

Comment: Same with `$total_amount = $amount;`, otherwise it just keeps getting overridden

Comment: Thanks @alexV pretty noobish mistake that one :/ 

Cheers for that